# Gitlab pipeline doesn't activate with .gitlab-ci.yml file in repo root

Tags: git, firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using GitLab for my CI/CD. I have a Firebase application where I am trying to deploy the functions. However, the pipeline does not activate/get created, even with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. I have enabled shared runners, my code is in my dev branch which I am referring to in the ci file.

My folder structure looks like (with `.gitlab-ci.yml` file at the root of the repo):

```
- .gitlab-ci.yml
- project
  - functions
    - ...
  - src
    - ...
```

My gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:12.13.0-alpine

variables:
  ENV: "dev"

before_script:
  - npm i -g firebase-tools

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

DeployFunctions:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd project/functions
    - npm install
    - cd ..
    - firebase deploy --only functions --token $TBT_DEV_FIREBASE_CI
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
    changes:
      - functions/**/*
```

When I lint the file using the GitLab CI Lint, and I lint it without selecting the option "Simulate a pipeline created for the default branch", the syntax seems to be correct. However, when I select that option, I get the following error:

```
No stages / jobs for this pipeline.
```

When I add the `Builder` job i.e. the following block, everything works fine:

```
...

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Builder:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Commencing build"

DeployFunctions:
  stage: deploy
  script:

...
```

This leads me to believe that I'm not correctly defining the `DeployFunctions` job. Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have disabled pipelines in options?

Comment: Nope, pipelines are enabled under Settings > General > Visibility, project features, permissions > Pipelines toggle.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that no pipeline gets created makes it seem that it's an issue with the `only: refs` tag. I linted your file, the syntax is correct.

Is your CI file included in your dev branch? As far as I'm concerned it should work as long as the .gitlab-ci.yml is tracked on the dev branch and you push to that branch. Did you do all of that?

Comment: You got me on the right tracks, but, it ended up not just being the only: refs, its also the changes block. I couldn't get any of them to work.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar issue a few weeks ago, someone was having trouble with the `only: changes:` tag combined with the wildcard operator, maybe this helps https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/59540

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my pipelines to create after removing some configuration from my .gitlab-ci.yml file. In the end I removed the entire `only` block. Somehow, the configuration under this block was wrong, including the `changes` block under `only`, even though the same configuration can be seen in many .gitlab-ci.yml examples.

```
image: node:12.13.0-alpine

before_script:
  - npm i -g firebase-tools

stages:
  - deploy

DeployFunctions:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd project/functions
    - npm install
    - cd ..
    - firebase deploy --only functions --token $DEV_FIREBASE_CI
```